# Configuring SMTPS in Virtualmin

Tags: email, ssl, postfix, smtp

I'm attempting to configure SMTPS in Virtualmin and am running into a roadblock.  I followed the [instructions here](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/email/smtps) without a problem but when I do the autoconfigure in Thunderbird it still says that the outgoing mail is unencrypted.

The steps I took (outlined in the link above) are that I added SMTP to the virtual server through `Edit Virtual Server` and then copied the SSL certificate over to Postfix via `Manage SSL Certificates`.  I restarted the whole server for good measure as well.  Might I be leaving something out?

I suppose I could try doing the manual configure in my email client (in case autoconfigure isn't picking up on the encryption), but I don't know what the proper outgoing parameters are for the manual configuration with regard to SSL and Authentication.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the [instructions here,](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/email/smtps) as mentioned above, I changed my autoconfig server template under **System Settings > Server Templates** (and under the dropdown menu "Edit template section")  **> Mail client auto-configuration**.  In the section **Thunderbird auto-configuration XML**, under the heading `outgoingServer`, I changed the port from `$SMTP_PORT` to `$SMTPS_Port` and selected **XMLtemplate below** as opposed to **Automatically generated**.  My XML template is therefore as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<clientConfig version="1.1">
  <emailProvider id="$SMTP_DOMAIN">
    <domain>$SMTP_DOMAIN</domain>
    <displayName>$OWNER Email</displayName>
    <displayShortName>$OWNER</displayShortName>
    <incomingServer type="imap">
      <hostname>$IMAP_HOST</hostname>
      <port>$IMAP_PORT</port>
      <socketType>$IMAP_TYPE</socketType>
      <authentication>$IMAP_ENC</authentication>
      <username>$SMTP_LOGIN</username>
    </incomingServer>
    <outgoingServer type="smtp">
      <hostname>$SMTP_HOST</hostname>
      <port>$SMTPS_PORT</port>
      <socketType>$SMTP_TYPE</socketType>
      <authentication>$SMTP_ENC</authentication>
      <username>$SMTP_LOGIN</username>
    </outgoingServer>
  </emailProvider>
</clientConfig>
```

If the variable `$SMTPS_Port` doesn't work for you, you can try manually entering port 465.  If you have any other issues, I'd recommend [this VirtualMin forum post](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/33449#comment-134682) where I got the answer.